# Significance of differences in coefficients when used to predict different responses

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, regression-coefficients

I am currently constructing a regression model meant to predict a given dependent variable - call it `IN`. I will also be constructing a model with the same independent variables to predict a second dependent variable - call it `OUT`. I would like to examine the difference between coefficients for the same independent variable across models. For example, if the coefficient for `VarX` is 0.2 in the `IN` model, and 0.3 in the `OUT` model, I want to be able to test whether this difference is significant. What is the best way to do this?

Additionally, I will want to run the `IN` model using slightly varied independent variables. My data varies over time, so I have fields for population size every year from 2003 to 2012. I want to run different versions of my model, using `IN` as my dependent variable, with each version using the population size of a different year. This will give me a series of coefficients - I want to be able to test whether the difference between coefficients for the "population size" variables is statistically significant. As above, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Interesting question -- although my perspective would be that a test of significance is of less interest than considering the effect sizes (coefficients) and confidence intervals to ask whether the two dependent variables have *materially* different values (and this would of course depend on how comparable the dependent variables are in terms of scale and so forth...)